# How to dump firmware from a PCB with an MCU and FPGA and make sure all data is extracted successfully?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, fpga, memory, firmware

I have an old PCB that is no longer manufactured. I'd like to get the firmware out of it, but it looks like it has an MCU on it and an Altera Cyclone FPGA first generation. I'm still learning how the PCB is constructed and I'm a novice at extracting firmware (I'm so sad that I didn't learn earlier to do this, because it looks so cool and is worth knowing), but I suspect that there are two firmwares, if I may call them that.

The one on the MCU runs and accepts requests from the machine's keypad. It drives motors and also checks the status of various sensors on the machine. In general, it performs all the functions of the machine.

The PCB is connected to another PCB (the second PCB is not of my interest, it is still in production. It is from a different manufacturer) and it's communicating with it and here the FPGA seems to be doing the work. Actually the FPGA receives signals from the second PCB and I guess tells the MCU what to do - which motor to drive, status of sensors, etc. I'm not sure why they use both - MCU and FPGA at all on this PCB. Probably the MCU can't accept such requests from the second PCB because it should do multiple things in parallel like move two motors at the same time, check the status of multiple sensors at the same time and the MCU can't do that.

Fortunately, the PCB has two open connections - a UART controller that is built on the PCB with USB-B from the PCB and I can connect to it with a simple USB-B to USB-A cable to the computer. On the other hand, there is also a JTAG open connection. It appears to be connected to flash memory on the PCB and FPGA. I verified this by looking at the PCB paths. Both MCU and FPGA are also connected together. I have the basics of dumping the firmware on the PCB, but I lack the knowledge of how I can extract both firmwares (if there are two).

I assume the MCU firmware is written in C and the FPGA firmware is written in HDL. How can I be sure that when I try to extract the information that I got all the data from all the FLASH and EEPROM on the MCU and FPGA?

I'm going to try to rebuild the exact same PCB and want to make sure all the data is extracted, so I can later upload it to the new PCB and still be able to do what it should do and communicate with the second PCB effectively.

Comment: Cross posted to reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/10iiqru/how_to_dump_firmware_from_a_pcb_with_an_mcu_and/

Comment: What makes you think the firmware is even dumpable? MCUs have lock bits to allow manufacturers to prevent cloning a product by just dumping the firmware. The FPGA configuration data may also be scrambled to prevent using it with another FPGA with different serial number. And it does not matter at all how the MCU firmware is made, C or whatever, or how FPGA configuration data is made, HDL or graphically, they are just binary data now.

Comment: Even if you are able to dump the MCU FW, the fact the it may have been written in C is almost irrelevant. C is a *compiled* language, so what's inside the MCU is "machine code", which can only be represented as assembler (for humans).

Comment: @Justme - I have a program acting like a driver which works by connecting to the built in UART controller on the PCB with USB-B from the PCB to the USB-A on the computer. It's a basic program to test the motors and check the status of the sensors. It's communicating with the MCU on the PCB. The company left open some ports with headers: UART controller with a USB-B and a JTAG 10 pin labeled as FPGA ISP on it. Considering the fact that they offered firmware update via one of their technicians back in the days, I strongly believe that they have no protection at all. It's not a huge company.

Comment: @Justme - I will try to dump the firmware by connecting to the MCU via the UART  and using Putty on Windows. I will see if there is any bootloader and use it to dump the firmware. But what about the FPGA firmware? I have Altera USB ByteBlaster to connect to the JTAG. I will use Quartus II programmer. Any other ideas to make sure that I dumped everything? Maybe I don't even have to use the USB ByteBlaster and dumping through the UART communication will be enough? Could you please let me know some ideas on how to approach this? Thank you!

Comment: Even if there is any bootloader, how do you know what to communicate with it, and why would a bootloader of a commercial device would allow reading of the firmware for cloning purposes? Which MCU it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In my opinion you can take several approaches:**

1. If both devices (MCU and FPGA) store their code/configuration in the same flash, you can simply download the contents via a dedicated reader (You can buy one, serial or parallel) and write the contents to the new chip on the new board.
2. You can just unsolder the flash and resolder it to the new board.
3. You can unsolder and resolder the FPGA and MCU (If they store their config internally and readout is locked)
4. You can connect to the MCU/FPGA via e.g. a JTAG-Probe and download the internal code/config if readout is not locked.
5. You can scan the internet/ask the manufacturer for the .bin files. With some luck they will provide them as they no longer manufactur the device in question.

As, in my opinion, the flash only holds the config for the FPGA you can download/reuse the contents from these chips. The MCU will, most likely, store its code internally. Therefore you will have to download (JTAG, if not locked) the code and flah it to a new device - or simply reuse the current device.

**My advice:**

Simply reuse the components in question (MCU, FPGA, Flash, EEPROM) by unsoldering and resoldering them.

This depends on the "solderability" of these devices and your skillset/tools available - but in my opinion this is the easiest route.
Also, if you lack the tools/skills/time, you can involve an "repair-shop" for these kind of tasks. They will charge a few hundred bucks, but this can be worth it (Mandatory machine controllers, defence equipment, what not).

**A few problems:**

The components (FPGA/MCU) may have code in them to check for device IDs on boot. This is a common feature to make "ripping it off" harder. If so, you will have to reuse the current devices. If not, you will have to dig through the code and find the "comparison" routine.

If the FPGA/MCU/Flash are in some "high density .35mm pitch 1000Pins package" you can run into trouble unsoldering/resoldering them quickly.

**Why use a FPGA/MCU tandem:**

There are many, many, and even more reasons to do that.
MCUs in general are targeted for special jobs - as FPGAs are.
BUT: a FPGA can be a simple MCU/dedicated FPGA. It can be what you want it to be.

So judging from the information available to me: I would say, that the FPGA does implement some custom Card<->Card interface reused by the design team. They opted with a FPGA as they maybe wanted special features or internal frame buffering or what not.

The MCU treats the FPGA as some sort of "external communication device" - quite like a UART/USB converter you can buy - and does the "heavy application lifting".

But maybe the FPGA does also implement the actual motor-drive logic and the MCU works as sort of "Sensor-Hub" reading currents and voltages or switches and whatnot.

We would need to trace out the PCB to form a clearer picture of the "assumed" block diagramm of the pcb - but you will never know for sure "what does what" as long as you dont dig thorugh the code/configuration, spend countless hours reading and thinking, measuring and testing.

**EDIT 1:**
To get more detailed (based on the comments) i append this edit.

1. As it seems, the used FPGA does not have any internal configuration. So all configuration will be stored on an external Device. Either, on boot, the fpga is configured directly from a Flash/EEPROM Memory (easy case) or via the MCU loading the firwame (maybe encrypted, but unlikely) from the flash and sending it to the FPGA (Not so easy case).

To get the contents of the FLASH/EEProm you will have to read it. You should obtain a datasheet for the specific memory used. Based on the exact information you can order/build a probe to read the memory contents. You will have to unsolder the IC to read from it.

When assembling your new PCB, you simply use the same probe to write the exact contents to the new FLASH IC !before! soldering.

2. To connect to the MCU you will have to get information on what interface is used. To do this, you have to find a datasheet. This will have information on what debug/programming interface is used. If i had to guess, i would go with JTAG.

You then have to order/build a probe for this pecific interface to connect to the controller - it is !very! unlikely that this can be bypased and instead be done via the UART port.

The downloading is usually as follows: You obtain the memory addreses from the datasheet (Flash x->y, eeprom a->b - the addresses) and use you probe via command line/GUI. You then tell it to download the content from addres (x or a) with a size of (y-x, b-a) and save it to your local machine.

On your new PCB you connect to the MCU via the probe again and tell it to upload the contents to the same addresses as they were downloaded from.

**In anycase:**

If you want to build your own PCB (why not reuse the old one and repair it?) you will have to download the FPGA configuration and the MCU software -both are important.

**EDIT 2:**

As you downloaded the FPGA configuration succesfully, you now have to continue with MCU firmware.

You can connect to the AVR MCU via the ISP header present on the board. Make sure to get the pinout correct: [ISP Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42093-AVR-ISP-mkII_UserGuide.pdf).

To verify, that the ISP is enabled/functional you can try the following:
Download the EEPROM content and check for a 0xFF byte. Then try to write that 0xFF byte to a known value ( e.g 0x12). Download the EEPROM content again. If the byte was changed, you can trust both FLASH and EEPROM downloads.

Make sure to also download the fuses - these are important too.

You can store these three files on your local machine to later on programm them onto your new device.

**EDIT 3:**

As you now have all four files required (FPGA config, MCU flash, MCU EEprom, MCU Fuses) you can rebuild your board.

But be aware: The MCU code may hide some ID-Checks, internal PCB speciic calibration, what not - so dont be happy to early!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I have two separate machines and the PCB on one of it is not working anymore. I have to copy the stuff from the one that currently works and reproduce it, so I can get the second machine to work as well.

Comment: I have a program acting like a driver which works by connecting to the built in UART controller on the PCB with USB-B from the PCB to the USB-A on the computer. It's a basic program to test the motors and check the status of the sensors. It's communicating with the MCU on the PCB. The company left open some ports with headers: UART controller with a USB-B and a JTAG 10 pin labeled as FPGA ISP on it. Considering the fact that they offered firmware update via one of their technicians back in the days, I strongly believe that they have no protection at all. It's not a huge company.

Comment: I will try to dump the firmware by connecting to the MCU via the UART and using Putty on Windows. I will see if there is any bootloader and use it to dump the firmware. But what about the FPGA firmware? I have Altera USB ByteBlaster to connect to the JTAG. I will use Quartus II programmer. Any other ideas to make sure that I dumped everything? Maybe I don't even have to use the USB ByteBlaster and dumping through the UART communication will be enough? Could you please let me know some ideas on how to approach this? Thank you!

Comment: @nRov I see. I guess the simplest way to get all Firmware - and make sure it is complete - is to do the follwing: Read the datasheet for the FPGA: Does it have nonvoltaile internal configuration? If so -> Try JTAG/whatever to connect to it and download it. If not: Just use the flash contents. What could be though: The controller writes config directly to the FPGA on every boot. So you will have to get the MCU firmware as well. There i would try JTAG (If unlocked you can download FLASH/EEPROM).

Comment: I also highly encourage you to not mess with the internal bootloader. It can be configured to hide certain memory reagions from readout. Check the datasheet which ISPs it uses (JTAG e.g). They should be available on the PCB (either via headers or pads). If either the MCU or FPGA are locked for readout: No practical way to get the full software as "known good" copy. Sure you can try the bootloader: But i would not expose a) my bootloader code for download via the bootloader and b) some config/logging/whatnot data in the eeprom/flash for download via the bootloader.

Comment: Do you possibly know why they opted to use both MCU and FPGA on the PCB instead of just an MCU? Am I correct by saying that the MCU can't communicate with the second PCB, because it must do multiple things in parallel like move two motors at the same time, check the status of multiple sensors at the same time and the FPGA can do that, so the MCU feeds the data to the FPGA upon boot and the FPGA can now communicate with the second PCB? If so, I should focus on extracting the only firmware from the MCU? And instead of JTAG, could I possibly use the available UART connection to extract the FW?

Comment: The JTAG 10-pin port on the PCB is labeled FPGA ISP. The things you say about the bootloader seem very logical, so if I want to dump the full data including the bootloader and everything (and if there is no protection) ... what would be the best approach? Can I still do it via PuTTy on Windows via UART COM serial connection?

Comment: This is the FPGA - Altera Cyclone first generation -> https://www.ibselectronics.com/ibsstore/ep1c6f256c8n-altera-fpga-275-03mhz-1-5v-256-fbga.html and this is the datasheet for it - > https://www.ibselectronics.com/ibsstore/datasheet/Altera/Cyclone_FPGA_Family.pdf | Any chance you can tell me if it has non-volatile memory? Is it 92160 bit as stated on the first website?

Comment: @nRov According to the datasheet there seems to be no internal non-volatile configuration present. So you can just copy/dump the flash contents of your FPGA-EEPROM/Flash (Make sure that the Flash IC is indeed connected to the FPGA and not the MCU). The best way to get the contents (EEPROM, Flash) of the MCU is to use a programming probe. Have a look at the datasheet which interface is implemented and get a probe (most likely JTAG). You can then download all contents - if they are not locked. Then, after building your own board, you can download the contents via the same probe again.

Comment: You can't expect to be able to dump firmware via serial port and a terminal program. Is there something you know about the device? Many MCUs don't even have a bootloader, do you know anything about the MCU? Which MCU it is?

Comment: @Justme - I examined the PCB more carefully and it appears to have the following components. ATmega2560 MCU, FPGA Altera Cyclone (EP1C3T100C8N), EPCS1 and 2 x SN74LVC245A Octal bus transceivers located between the MCU and the FPGA. I guess they are both connected to each other. Please look at the additional comment below.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Well, if there is no internal non-volatile memory on the FPGA how it will know to load data from the external memory chip EPCS1?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - I have some weird result with the last tests I did. I was able to connect an Altera USB ByteBlaster to the JTAG 10 pin port and extract the content of the EPCS1 which is 128KB via the Quartus II Programmer using Active Serial Connection. Everything looks good, but when I tried to connect to the Altera Cyclone FPGA (EP1C3T100C8N) using the Auto Detect feature from the Quartus II programmer to the JTAG chain, then I got an error that the JTAG chain could not be found.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Is the extracted data as a .pof file from the EPCS1 valuable and how will the FPGA know to load data from it if I restore it to another PCB? I actually tried to restore it on the same PCB I run these tests on but it can't find the FPGA at all only the EPCS1... could it be because I have to erase it first, so it will go in some sort of debug mode and be able to be reprogrammed? The pathways on the PCB from the EPCS1 are going to the FPGA Altera Cyclone, so they must be definitely wired together. .

Comment: For the ATmega2560 MCU I will get a USBasp programmer and try to extract both the Flash and the EEPROM using avrdude. As it appears, there is a 6-pin ICSP port on the PCB. In theory it should work this way if it's not protected, right?

Comment: @nRov The FPGA does not need any non-volatile memory to know how to read external memory. The AVR may have ISP disabled, or if it doesn't, it may have readout protection enabled, in which case it will just read some random looking data instead of actual data.

Comment: @nRov Sounds great! The FPGA will load the data from eterna storage upon boot by itself. No Code/Configuration is required for this - it is handled by the chip itself by default. To make sure the ISP is enabled on the AVR MCU, you could try to read the eeprom first. Then examine the file and find a byte which is 0xFF. Try to write it to something else. Download it again and check it. If you can write to the eeprom the ISP is enabled and you can trust both, Flash and eeprom files.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - If I understood correctly: --> 
I can use AVRDUDESS (a GUI for avrdude) and connect to the 6 pin ISP port with the USBasp programmer and first read the EEPROM from the MCU, open the file with a hex editor and find any 0xFF byte in it and change it to any known value such as 0x12, save it, and then use the Write function in AVRDUDESS to upload it again to the EEPROM of the MCU. Then I have to download it again, open it with the hex editor and check if the byte I edited is really changed? And about the fuses, how do I download them? I guess I can't use AVRDUDESS for that?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Your original answer with the additional edits becomes really detailed and helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @nRov You are welcome. And no, you dont have to write the entire eeprom. AVRDUDE should have commands to write a single byte as well - just in case something goes wrong. If your GUI version does not support this, you can try MICROCHIP studio as well. It has all the needs build in to connect and play with AVR devices.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - I will try it tomorrow. Just in case I run into a problem with the MICROCHIP studio, can I still do it the way I described by reading the EEPROM file with a hex editor and changing any random 0xFF byte to 0x12 and then writing the entire EEPROM --> if successful then I can trust them both the flash and the eeprom? Regarding saving the fuses, does MICROCHIP studio offer this as an option to save them to a file and later reprogram them on the cloned board? Aren't they saved to the eeprom?

Comment: @nRov Yeah, you can still do it this way. MICROCHIP Studio allows to download the fuses. AVRDUDE should as well. They are not stored in the EEPROM. Fuses are kind of EEPROM/kind of flash. Depends how you look at it - but they are treated as "some special kind of very fundamental configuration bits" in the AVR controllers - so neither flash nor eeprom.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - I guess we can conclude that if I erase the entire contents of the external ECPS1 memory of the FPGA and the MCU (Flash & EEPROM), then rewrite it again on the same PCB and if it works, it means that the MCU code is NOT hiding any ID-Checks, internal PCB speciic calibration or something and everything is successfully dumped so I can proceed to clone the PCB somewhere?

Comment: @nRov Hmmm not that easy. You chips are still the same - so they could check the memory contents against some ID which did not change as the chips are the same.

Also calibration: Imagine you have some sort of external circuit which has tolerances due to component variations. A common approach is to "dial the offsets" in software. But your hardware did not change: So it should work as intendet. If the entire board is purely digitl, this is not an issue.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent There is a small PCB (without any logic, no MCU) to handle the power supply and this small PCB connects the power to the main PCB that I am trying to duplicate. I assume this is done because the power supply is far away from the main PCB, so they made this additional PCB to handle this. What I understand is that I can't be 100% sure even if I have successfully dumped all the contents until I actually duplicate the PCB and reprogram it with the data I have? How about an easier way to find a similar MCU and external EPCS1 memory for the FPGA and re-solder them then reprogram?

Comment: @nRov If its only a power input board you should be good to go. And yes - you cant be 100% sure if it works. But from what i hear: Should be >95% :). The problem is not the MCU or the flash IC itself, rather the contents of the MCU memory in particular. There could be a routine: Look in my memory for a ID - which was written there during factory programming - and compare it with the specific device ID individually assigned to each MCU IC by the silicon vendor. If they match: I know, that my controller is the same as in the factory. Aka nobody has just copied my code to a new board.

Comment: @nRov Your FPGA should work just fine, as it does not have modern encryption features. The MCU protection can be present. It is common in some kinds of application. But it is - in my opinion - not likely to be there. If they did not lock the MCU for code download, they did not bother to protect their softare at all - so why should they implement this feature?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - I was able to successfully download the MCU data (Flash & EEPROM) and took a picture of the fuses because there was no option in the application (AVRDUDESS GUI) to save them. Are these fuses sufficient or am I missing something? - [https://i.ibb.co/VJxfMTL/fuses.png](https://i.ibb.co/VJxfMTL/fuses.png)

Comment: And also the USBasp I got really disappointed me because it worked once every 5-6 connections. I also didn't find an option to connect to Microchip Studio. Can you recommend another good AVR programmer (6 pin port)? And regarding the MCU data, I saved it to both .hex and raw binary with no extension, does it really matter? Also, having successfully dumped all the contents (MCU - FLASH & EEPROM / FPGA - EPCS1 memory), I guess I can now safely move on to cloning the actual PCB, or maybe I'll have to find new MCU / EPCS1 Flash / FPGA first and try to solder them together so I can test it?

Comment: I tried another app called eXtreme Burner but it couldn't connect to the MCU at all, but I saw a feature in it called Calibration near the fuses in this app, however the app couldn't connect at all to test it. I'm afraid I'm missing something other than these fuses I showed you above.

Comment: @nRov The fuses look good. You will have to programm them to the new "virgin" MCU. And no, your are not missing something. Flash/EEProm/fuses is all you car about on the MCU and Flash is all you care about on the FPGA. The MCU calibration is done by Microchip during manufacturing - it sets clock speeds and calibration...So no worrys. The extension of the files does not matter, as long as your programming tool can use them (Which it should, as you downloaded it with it). You could buy a new MCU and a new flash, programm them and test solder them. But cloning your board is now an option.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Thank you very much for your help! About Altera Cyclone FPGA first generation - [https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/EP1C6T144C8N](https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/EP1C6T144C8N) - Here it says it has 4 Kbit Embedded Block RAM EBR. This should be a volatile type of memory, right? Surely this particular FPGA has no internal non-volatile memory to worry about? Could you please recommend another AVR programmer that should work with Microchip Studio? The USBasp on Windows is a real pain. It works once every 5-6 connections and then need to restart the PC.

Comment: @nRov Block RAM is what it says it is: RAM. So volatile memory -> No worrys! You could try the "Atmel ICE" programmer. I used it back in the day - worked like a treat as far as i remeber. And is, ofcourse, fully integrated into micrchip studio.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Thank you so much! I just accepted your answer.  Sorry, but I had forgotten that the platform required it. Could you please tell me what these connectors are used for on the PCB? The paths seem to go directly to the MCU - [https://i.ibb.co/P4VZMm7/654533423.jpg](https://i.ibb.co/P4VZMm7/654533423.jpg)

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Here is the updated image. - [https://i.ibb.co/P4zQxgL/654533423.jpg](https://i.ibb.co/P4zQxgL/654533423.jpg) - Is it something to do with debugging and the FTDI cable? What kind of tool can I attach to one of these ports?

Comment: @nRov I dont know whatthese ports connect too. Maye these are used during debugging/developement and were never removed from the layout. Butre thez required for JTAGing into the MCU/The FPGA?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - There are separate ISP headers to connect to a 10-pin port that I used to connect to the FPGA's external EPCS1 memory via an active serial connection on the Quartus II programmer and another 6-pin port for the AVR programming. So I'm not sure what those ports in the picture are for because I've never used them. Could these ports also be used to program the MCU and external EPCS1 memory in some other way, or most likely they are there for debugging/monitoring via some software created by the manufacturer? If you had to guess, what's your opinion? Once again thank you!

Comment: @nRov I guess they are of the later case. Usually there is onlz one "Programming-Port" associated with every device.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - Okay, and about the EPCS1 - I was able to connect to this external EPCS1 memory with the USB Blaster via active serial programming on the Quartus II programmer, but I couldn't connect via the same port via JTAG connection on the Quartus II to the FPGA itself. I guess my attempt to connect directly to the FPGA failed because it's not connected to the port, only to the external EPCS1 memory and I can't connect to the FPGA through the external memory?

Comment: @nRov You Maybe the two devices are in a JTAG series. Does your blaster have the ability to scan for multiple devices on the same bus?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent - How do I check if my Blaster has this feature?  I downloaded the .pof file from the external EPCS1 memory using Active Serial Programming (it says so in the Quartus II application). I tried using another connection through the Quartus II application, such as JTAG, but I couldn't connect to the FPGA, nor to the external EPCS1 memory. The only possible connection was to use Active Serial Programming to EPCS1. There was an auto detect feature in the Quartus II app, but it couldn't detect any devices as I recall. Any ideas why I can only connect to the EPCS1 but not the FPGA?